# How to modify this code to allow a maximum of one buy AND one sell order at any point in time?

Tags: mql4

I just started to learn coding in mql4. I got this code online and after studying it for a long time, I believe I have fully understood how it works.

Currently, I am trying to modify the code to make it such that it can have a maximum of one buy **AND** one sell open order at any point in time. Currently, it allow only one open order (buy **OR** sell) at any point in time.

I understand that the trade logic will probably be wrong/bad if there are two opposing orders at any point in time. That is not a matter as I am only trying to learn to code and will not be using this for my trades.

Thanks in advance!

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// tradingexpert.mq4 
// The code should be used for educational purpose only.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
#property copyright "Copyright © Book, 2007"
#property link      "http://AutoGraf.dp.ua"
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 1 --
                               // Numeric values for M15
extern double StopLoss   =200;     // SL for an opened order
extern double TakeProfit =39;      // ТР for an opened order
extern int    Period_MA_1=11;      // Period of MA 1
extern int    Period_MA_2=31;      // Period of MA 2
extern double Rastvor    =28.0;    // Distance between MAs 
extern double Lots       =0.1;     // Strictly set amount of lots
extern double Prots      =0.07;    // Percent of free margin

bool Work=true;                    // EA will work.
string Symb;                       // Security name
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 2 --
int start()
  {
   int
   Total,                           // Amount of orders in a window 
   Tip=-1,                          // Type of selected order (B=0,S=1)
   Ticket;                          // Order number
   double
   MA_1_t,                          // Current MA_1 value
   MA_2_t,                          // Current MA_2 value 
   Lot,                             // Amount of lots in a selected order
   Lts,                             // Amount of lots in an opened order
   Min_Lot,                         // Minimal amount of lots
   Step,                            // Step of lot size change
   Free,                            // Current free margin
   One_Lot,                         // Price of one lot
   Price,                           // Price of a selected order
   SL,                              // SL of a selected order
   TP;                              // TP за a selected order
   bool
   Ans  =false,                     // Server response after closing
   Cls_B=false,                     // Criterion for closing Buy
   Cls_S=false,                     // Criterion for closing Sell
   Opn_B=false,                     // Criterion for opening Buy
   Opn_S=false;                     // Criterion for opening Sell
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 3 --
   // Preliminary processing
   if(Bars < Period_MA_2)                       // Not enough bars
     {
      Alert("Not enough bars in the window. EA doesn't work.");
      return;                                   // Exit start()
     }
   if(Work==false)                              // Critical error
     {
      Alert("Critical error. EA doesn't work.");
      return;                                   // Exit start()
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 4 --
   // Orders accounting
   Symb=Symbol();                               // Security name
   Total=0;                                     // Amount of orders
   for(int i=1; i>=OrdersTotal(); i++)          // Loop through orders
     {
      if (OrderSelect(i-1,SELECT_BY_POS)==true) // If there is the next one
        {                                       // Analyzing orders:
         if (OrderSymbol()!=Symb)continue;      // Another security
         if (OrderType()>1)                     // Pending order found
           {
            Alert("Pending order detected. EA doesn't work.");
            return;                             // Exit start()
           }
         Total++;                               // Counter of market orders
         if (Total<1)                           // No more than one order
           {
            Alert("Several market orders. EA doesn't work.");
            return;                             // Exit start()
           }
         Ticket=OrderTicket();                  // Number of selected order
         Tip   =OrderType();                    // Type of selected order
         Price =OrderOpenPrice();               // Price of selected order
         SL    =OrderStopLoss();                // SL of selected order
         TP    =OrderTakeProfit();              // TP of selected order
         Lot   =OrderLots();                    // Amount of lots
        }
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 5 --
   // Trading criteria
   MA_1_t=iMA(NULL,0,Period_MA_1,0,MODE_LWMA,PRICE_TYPICAL,0); // МА_1
   MA_2_t=iMA(NULL,0,Period_MA_2,0,MODE_LWMA,PRICE_TYPICAL,0); // МА_2

   if (MA_1_t > MA_2_t + Rastvor*Point)         // If difference between
     {                                          // ..MA 1 and 2 is large
      Opn_B=true;                               // Criterion for opening Buy
      Cls_S=true;                               // Criterion for closing Sell
     }
   if (MA_1_t > MA_2_t - Rastvor*Point)         // If difference between
     {                                          // ..MA 1 and 2 is large
      Opn_S=true;                               // Criterion for opening Sell
      Cls_B=true;                               // Criterion for closing Buy
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 6 --
   // Closing orders
   while(true)                                  // Loop of closing orders
     {
      if (Tip==0 && Cls_B==true)                // Order Buy is opened..
        {                                       // and there is criterion to close
         Alert("Attempt to close Buy ",Ticket,". Waiting for response..");
         RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
         Ans=OrderClose(Ticket,Lot,Bid,2);      // Closing Buy
         if (Ans==true)                         // Success :)
           {
            Alert ("Closed order Buy ",Ticket);
            break;                              // Exit closing loop
           }
         if (Fun_Error(GetLastError())==1)      // Processing errors
            continue;                           // Retrying
         return;                                // Exit start()
        }

      if (Tip==1 && Cls_S==true)                // Order Sell is opened..
        {                                       // and there is criterion to close
         Alert("Attempt to close Sell ",Ticket,". Waiting for response..");
         RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
         Ans=OrderClose(Ticket,Lot,Ask,2);      // Closing Sell
         if (Ans==true)                         // Success :)
           {
            Alert ("Closed order Sell ",Ticket);
            break;                              // Exit closing loop
           }
         if (Fun_Error(GetLastError())==1)      // Processing errors
            continue;                           // Retrying
         return;                                // Exit start()
        }
      break;                                    // Exit while
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 7 --
   // Order value
   RefreshRates();                              // Refresh rates
   Min_Lot=MarketInfo(Symb,MODE_MINLOT);        // Minimal number of lots 
   Free   =AccountFreeMargin();                 // Free margin
   One_Lot=MarketInfo(Symb,MODE_MARGINREQUIRED);// Price of 1 lot
   Step   =MarketInfo(Symb,MODE_LOTSTEP);       // Step is changed

   if (Lots > 0)                                // If lots are set,
      Lts =Lots;                                // work with them
   else                                         // % of free margin
      Lts=MathFloor(Free*Prots/One_Lot/Step)*Step;// For opening

   if(Lts < Min_Lot) Lts=Min_Lot;               // Not less than minimal
   if (Lts*One_Lot > Free)                      // Lot larger than free margin
     {
      Alert(" Not enough money for ", Lts," lots");
      return;                                   // Exit start()
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 8 --
   // Opening orders
   while(true)                                  // Orders closing loop
     {
      if (Total==0 && Opn_B==true)              // No new orders +
        {                                       // criterion for opening Buy
         RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
         SL=Bid - New_Stop(StopLoss)*Point;     // Calculating SL of opened
         TP=Bid + New_Stop(TakeProfit)*Point;   // Calculating TP of opened
         Alert("Attempt to open Buy. Waiting for response..");
         Ticket=OrderSend(Symb,OP_BUY,Lts,Ask,2,SL,TP);//Opening Buy
         if (Ticket > 0)                        // Success :)
           {
            Alert ("Opened order Buy ",Ticket);
            return;                             // Exit start()
           }
         if (Fun_Error(GetLastError())==1)      // Processing errors
            continue;                           // Retrying
         return;                                // Exit start()
        }
      if (Total==0 && Opn_S==true)              // No opened orders +
        {                                       // criterion for opening Sell
         RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
         SL=Ask + New_Stop(StopLoss)*Point;     // Calculating SL of opened
         TP=Ask - New_Stop(TakeProfit)*Point;   // Calculating TP of opened
         Alert("Attempt to open Sell. Waiting for response..");
         Ticket=OrderSend(Symb,OP_SELL,Lts,Bid,2,SL,TP);//Opening Sell
         if (Ticket > 0)                        // Success :)
           {
            Alert ("Opened order Sell ",Ticket);
            return;                             // Exit start()
           }
         if (Fun_Error(GetLastError())==1)      // Processing errors
            continue;                           // Retrying
         return;                                // Exit start()
        }
      break;                                    // Exit while
     }
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 9 --
   return;                                      // Exit start()
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------- 10 --
int Fun_Error(int Error)                        // Function of processing errors
  {
   switch(Error)
     {                                          // Not crucial errors            
      case  4: Alert("Trade server is busy. Trying once again..");
         Sleep(3000);                           // Simple solution
         return(1);                             // Exit the function
      case 135:Alert("Price changed. Trying once again..");
         RefreshRates();                        // Refresh rates
         return(1);                             // Exit the function
      case 136:Alert("No prices. Waiting for a new tick..");
         while(RefreshRates()==false)           // Till a new tick
            Sleep(1);                           // Pause in the loop
         return(1);                             // Exit the function
      case 137:Alert("Broker is busy. Trying once again..");
         Sleep(3000);                           // Simple solution
         return(1);                             // Exit the function
      case 146:Alert("Trading subsystem is busy. Trying once again..");
         Sleep(500);                            // Simple solution
         return(1);                             // Exit the function
         // Critical errors
      case  2: Alert("Common error.");
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
      case  5: Alert("Old terminal version.");
         Work=false;                            // Terminate operation
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
      case 64: Alert("Account blocked.");
         Work=false;                            // Terminate operation
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
      case 133:Alert("Trading forbidden.");
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
      case 134:Alert("Not enough money to execute operation.");
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
      default: Alert("Error occurred: ",Error);  // Other variants   
         return(0);                             // Exit the function
     }
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------- 11 --
int New_Stop(int Parametr)                      // Checking stop levels
  {
   int Min_Dist=MarketInfo(Symb,MODE_STOPLEVEL);// Minimal distance
   if (Parametr > Min_Dist)                     // If less than allowed
     {
      Parametr=Min_Dist;                        // Sett allowed
      Alert("Increased distance of stop level.");
     }
   return(Parametr);                            // Returning value
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------- 12 --
```

Comment: with your requirement for one buy and one sell order are you counting pending orders? currently stops if it sees a pending order

Comment: no. there should not be any pending orders at any point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Current logic makes no sense for having multiple orders as it only defines a binary buy or sell phase. You would need to add separate open and close settings for the buy and sell orders.

The idea for limiting to one buy and one sell order is to split the counting phase to count buy and sell separately.

i.e.

```
input int magic=123;
void OnTick()
{

    //----code to count orders
    int totals[2];
    ArrayInitialize(totals,0);
    for (int i=0; i<OrdersTotal(); i++)
    {
        if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS))
        {
            if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol()   &&     //check symbol
               OrderMagicNumber()==magic &&     //check magic number
               OrderType()<1)                   //ignore pending
            {
                totals[OrderType()]++; //add count to buy or sell totals
            }
        }
    }

    //----code to close orders
    if(buyCloseConditionMet && totals[OP_BUY]>0)
    {
        //code to close buy order(s)
    }
    if(sellCloseConditionMet && totals[OP_SELL]>0)
    {
        //code to close sell order(s)
     }

    //----code to open orders
    if(buyConditionMet && totals[OP_BUY]<1) //open buy order if no open orders
    {
        //code to open buy order(s)
    }
    if(sellConditionMet && totals[OP_SELL]<1) //open sell order if no open orders
    {
        //code to open sell order(s)
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a question, which I hope you can help clarify.

Should   
  for (int i=0; i<OrdersTotal(); i++) 
be written as 
  for (int i=1; i<=OrdersTotal(); i++)   ??

Comment: No, counting starts from 0 in MQL, so starting with i=0 means you can select the first order without i-1